How to encourage identification tag users to elaborate in their titles?
I've been editing a lot recently, (I'm the only guy on the editor list,) and titles are bugging me.
What are we supposed to get from "what is this piece", "where this brick from" or "what number is this part"?
I know there has to be a better way to name your question. If it has a good title, people will answer and upvote it. Sometimes I make a title edit, but while I enjoy moderating, I can't do it for you.
How should we go about encouraging a title that explains its subject properly?

Poor quality identification questions and non-descriptive titles often go hand in hand. They have been an ongoing problem for the site. 
First of all, we should encourage users to put reasonable effort into researching the parts they're interested in. We can do this by making people more aware of part/set libraries (such as Bricklink, Peeron and Brickset) as well as part/piece numbers that can be found hidden in most bricks.
Last year, I asked for support to have a 'how-to-ask' tips for identification tags, we had support for the idea and I had contacted a Stack Exchange Community Manager to get the featured added. I'm still hoping to hear from him and I've sent a reminder via SE chat to see if it can be implemented.
UPDATE: The 'how-to-ask' tip is now live for the identification tag! 

We could probably edit the tag on part-id and id to directly ask them to use a title that describes the question.
